# Android 9 patch image stopped to work after update to com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha2

Tags: android, android-studio, nine-patch, android-studio-3.0

After update to com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha2 and Android Studio 3.0 Canary 2.0 , my 9 patch stoped to work, now only show the png distorted and with the black dots, not recognizing the 9 patch after building the app, on the Editor shows normal.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/out_message_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">
```

Comment: Maybe a bug in AS 3.0, it's still in alpha. You should post to Android bug report.
PS: I would recommend using vector rather than 9 Patch as it's much more efficient.

Comment: Thanks, I posted this in bug report, but I'll see more about vector.